# Iterate an array w/ explicit object type in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an array:

```
let individualScores = [75, 43, 103, 87, 12]
```

And I iterate like this:

```
for score in individualScores {

}
```

However, is there a way to declare the object type explicitly?  I think it would come in handy later w/ custom objects, or other reasons.  Something like:

```
for Integer score in individualScores {

}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When you type a variable, you do:

```
var score: Int
```

And you do the same in a loop:

```
for score: Int in individualScores {

}
```

It seems to be pretty consistent in that regard.

Comment: Anybody else getting a segfault 11 from the compiler when doing this in Swift 2.0? I find I have to cast it myself in a subsequent line...

Comment: @elsurudo A segfault in a compiler is a compiler bug (probably a "we haven't yet implemented parsing this syntax" bug).

Comment: Yeah for sure. I've been finding a bunch of these, although slightly less with the latest Xcode GM. If I wasn't so lazy and had the time I'd file some radars, but alas...

Comment: @elsurudo Yep same segfault 11 here when I do this iteration... What the hell Swift :(

Comment: Simple types (like `Int`) work but anything more complex segfaults the compiler in Xcode 7.0

Answer (score 5):

yes its possible

```
let individualScores:Int[] = [75, 43, 103, 87, 12]

for score:Int in individualScores {

}
```

Comment: At some point, Swift must have changed because a tutorial had me doing `let possibleTipsExplicit:[Double] = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]` but your example fixed my error when I used `let possibleTipsExplicit:Double[] = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]`. Even the example on Apple's own site is the incorrect version.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can explicitly specify the type if you wish.

```
let individualScores = [75, 43, 103, 87, 12]

for score: Int in individualScores {
    println(score)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicit type declarations follow an identifier declaration with a colon.

```
for score: Int in individualScores {
    // ...
}

let π: Double = 3.1415926535897932
var x: Int = 10
```

You can read it "x is an Int". See [A Swift Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_1).

The loop variable (`score`) is explicitly and strongly typed whether you declare the type or not — it comes from the type of the array you're iterating through. Swift knows `individualScores` is an `Int[]`, short for an `Array<Int>` because you declared it with integer literals. See [Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_234) for more about how that works.