# Iterating using explicit types in Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004103/iterate-an-array-w-explicit-object-type-in-swift) using

```
for score: Int in individualScores {

}
```

allows you to use an explicit type to iterate over values. However, when I try this with an object like this

```
for family : UIFont in UIFont.familyNames() {
    println("Fam: \(family)")
}
```

I get the error "Type annotation does not match contextual type 'AnyObject'" What's causing this error, and how can I iterate over NSObject subclasses in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well ,for starters, familyNames returns NSStrings, not UIFonts.  But, that aside, try casting the array, not the result of the iteration:

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames() as [String] {
    println("fam: \(family)")
}
```

Comment: String[] to be written as [String]

Comment: Yeah, they changed it somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make this:

```
for family: AnyObject in UIFont.familyNames() {
   println("Fam: \(family)")
}
```